# How do i show that this fuction is not injective?

Tags: calculus, functions, parametrization

The function is given as:
$$f: \begin{cases} 
\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\ 
t \mapsto (t²-1,t³-t)
\end{cases}$$
i know that this is function class $C^\infty$

Comment: You simply observe that $f(1)=f(-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(-1)=(0,0), f(1)=(0,0)$
Hence, the function is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(1)=(0,0)=f(-1).$  Conclusion ?